# Jetty: Configure SSL connector to only serve specific resource(s)

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

Apologies in advance if I'm using terms incorrectly, I'm not familiar with Jetty.

I've attached an SSL connector to my Jetty server.  Now, my public resources are accessible through both `http` and `https`.  I would like to restrict the resources served from `https`, preferably by checking against some URI pattern. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard servlet `<security-constraint>` configurations in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`

Example:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Force SSL on /private/ url-patterns</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```